# How can I change the font color of a disabled TextField in mui?

Tags: material-ui

I need to change the font color of a disabled TextField in Material-UI

I've tried the following but it does not work:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  input: {
    color: theme.palette.text.primary,
  },
}));

function Example() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <TextField InputProps={{ className: classes.input }} />
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to figure out how its done:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  disabledInput: {
    color: theme.palette.text.primary,
  },
}));

function Example() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <TextField 
    InputProps={{ classes: { disabled: classes.disabledInput } }}
  />
}
```